# How to sort the docs when use scroll api in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently I'm reading Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide. When I read a section about [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scroll.html), I got some problem. The book says that :

> The costly part of deep pagination is the global sorting of results, but if we disable sorting, then we can return all documents quite cheaply. To do this, we sort by _doc. This instructs Elasticsearch just return the next batch of results from every shard that still has results to return.

Then the question came. If I'd like to sort the results, then does it mean that I still will get bad performance? If so, how to solve the deep pagination problem? Is there anyone can help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you using elasticsearch with php

Comment: No, I just use curl and maybe replace it with Python later.